# Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}

Tags: pgfplots, units

I am using Ti*k*Z to draw plots in `LaTeX`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
xmin=0, xmax=100,
ymin=0, ymax=120,
xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=square,]
coordinates {(0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)};
\legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the error `**Undefined control sequence. \end{axis}**` during compilation using *Pdf LaTeX* in *TeXStudio*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code complains about `\textcelsius` being unknown. Use `\usepackage{textcomp}` to get this command.

Or use `\usepackage{siunitx}` and `xlabel={Temperature [\si{\celsius}]}`.

For the chemical formula the usage of a chemical package might be more  appropiate than using math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
xlabel={Temperature [\si{\celsius}]},
ylabel={Solubility [\si{g} per \SI{100}{g} water]},
xmin=0, xmax=100,
ymin=0, ymax=120,
xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=square,]
coordinates {(0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)};
\legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
xmin=0, xmax=100,
ymin=0, ymax=120,
xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=square,]
coordinates {(0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)};
\legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Christan Hupfer \usepackage{textcomp} is working fine. But \usepackage{siunitx} is not working.

Comment: @LitunJohn: `siunitx` is not working? Well, I've provided both styles

Comment: Okay, How can I change the design of the plot?

Comment: @LitunJohn: That's another question ;-)